# Santa Claus does not exist. Therefore, something does not exist. Valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

My lecturer defines logical validity (in the English language) like so:

'An argument is logically valid if and only if there is no (uniform) interpretation (of subject-specific expressions) under which the premises are all true, and the conclusion is false.'

He contrasts subject-specific expressions (e.g., Donald Trump, Aristotle, chemical element, London), with logical expressions (i.e., if, not, if and only if, every, some). Logical expressions are not subject to re-interpretation; they keep their standard English meanings all the time.

My question is this: is the following argument valid?

P1: Santa Claus does not exist.
C: Something does not exist.

Now, on the one hand, I'm inclined to say yes: if I replace 'Santa Clause' with any other noun, or I replace the property of *does not exist* with any other property, the resulting argument is such that: if the premises are true, so too is the conclusion.

On the other hand, I'm hesistant to say yes: if I replace **'something'** with, for example, 'a car', then the resulting argument seems to involve a true premise, and a false conclusion.

Moreover, I'd unhesitatingly say that the following argument is valid:

P1: Santa Claus does not exist. P2: Santa Claus is something. C: Something does not exist.

Could Santa Clause *not* be 'something'? From another angle: is 'something' a 'subject-specific expression'? I'm inclined to think it is *not*, but I'm not sure how to justify this thought. (My inkling is that it has something (lol) to do with the fact that 'something' is a pronoun, whilst 'a car' is a noun? Also, I'm aware that the argument in question involves a valid rule of inference in FOL. But I wonder if this is one of those cases where validity in FOL comes apart from more informal characterisations of validity in the English language (e.g., http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/intro/notes/leibniz-epist.html).)

Comment: What does 'something' mean? Can something that doesn't exist really be something? I would translate the sentence "something har property P" to $\exists x : P(x)$. But if $P(x)$ means "$x$ does not exist" then we get a contradiction: "there exists $x$ such that $x$ does not exist."

Comment: Great question! I think there are pretty deep ambiguities in "exists" and our quantification scope (less formally what we mean by "something" when we say "something does not exist") that will make it hard to get an absolute answer in either direction. 

I can give a context where your argument holds: you're quantifying over concepts, and "exist" in "something does not exist" means physically realized. Then your argument becomes a proof that there is a concept that is not physically realized.

Comment: If, however, you want "exists" to mean exactly what it means logically ($y$ exists if $\exists x\ x=y$) then there's no way of making your argument valid for the reasons described by @md2perpe

Comment: You might get better answers on philosophy stackexchange.

Comment: Your concern is right. In "standard" FOL, every individual constant (e.g. proper name, like Santa) must have reference. This means that a language with the name Santa must be interpreted in a domain where Santa exists. The second issue is that in standard FOL we cannot translate "exists" both with a quantifier $\exists x$ and with a predicate $E(x)$. Thus, we cannot write $\lnot \exists x E(x)$.

Comment: But there are alternatives; see [Free Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/).

Comment: As per answer below, if $\text {Santa}$ is an individual constant, we have $\text {Santa}=\text {Santa}$  by equality axioms and thus $\exists x (x = \text {Santa})$ is a valid FOL formula. FOL is consistent, and thus we cannot derive:  $\lnot \exists x (x = \text {Santa})$

Comment: We may try with a predicate $\text {Santa}(x)$; in this way we may express the fact that this predicate is not instantiated: $\lnot \exists x \text {Santa}(x)$. If we move to SOL, we may derive $\exists P \lnot \exists x \text P(x)$. And this can be a "reasonable" symbolization of "Something does not exist".

Comment: The argument above may sound "less unnatural" if we use the predicate $\text {RoundSquare}(x)$

Answer (score 3):

Alex Kruckman is right, this is more philosophy than maths. Let me give a very brief answer that may be enough for your purposes.

There is the mainstream (kantian) answer to this kind of antinomy: existence is not a predicate. A Russell-Frege analysis of "Santa Claus does not exist" is

$\neg\exists x; x$ is Santa Claus.

The lesson here is that logical form is not necessarily unique and equal to the grammatical form (Frege). The (logical) subject of the sentence is not Santa Claus, but the property of being Santa Claus, and the sentence says that the extension of this property is empty.

This is the basis of Quine's meta-ontology: existence is not a predicate, it is univocal, it is the same as being and it is adequately captured by the existential quantifier.
"Something does not exist" does not correspond to a logical sentence in this account.

Of course, there are alternative views on this topic. There is Meinong's meta-ontology, for example, in which there are things that subsist but do not exist (being is not the same as existence). Santa Claus could be an example. In this account, the argument that you have given is taken to be valid. I shall stop here.

Answer (score 1):

> **P1**: Santa Claus does not exist.
> **C**: Something does not exist.
>
> **P1**: Santa Claus does not exist.
> **P2**: Santa Claus is something.
> **C**: Something does not exist.

The above arguments are phrased for maximal ambiguity.

Since **C** clearly isn't intended to mean that some *particular* thing does not exist (something that exists does not exist??), its only sensible reading is that nothing exists, that is, that **the discourse universe is empty**. This reading immediately prevents us from invoking a syllogism to "unhesitatingly" say that the second argument is valid. More significantly, this reading means that sentence **C** is not even in the object language.

In **P2**, the word "is" clearly is intended to mean not identity/equality but set membership, that is, that **P2** means that Santa Claus belongs to the set of somethings, that is, that Santa Claus exists, that is, that **the discourse universe contains, say, $s$ specifically, where $s$ stands for Santa Claus**. So, sentence **P2** is not in the object language either.

For **P1**, notice that we cannot treat "is Santa Claus" as a predicate, as this would be inconsistent with **P2**'s phrasing. By similar reasoning as for **C**, the only sensible reading of **P1** is that **nothing in the discourse universe can be identified as Santa Claus**.

Thus, none of sentences **P1**, **P2** and **C** are actually in the object language, and neither are the two given arguments. The first argument is an invalid metalanguage argument, while the second argument is a valid but unsound metalanguage argument.